# Difficulty with parsing error JSON from ServiceNow REST API

Tags: c#, json, rest, servicenow

I have been writing a tool in C# that makes a few calls to ServiceNow via the table REST API. I am using RESTsharp to make the REST calls, and JSON.net to deserialize the results. This seems to work very well for queries that don't return an error.

```
        try
        {

            DataSet dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(response.Content);
            results = dataset.Tables["result"];

            return (results);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
         ....
        }
```

However, when an error is returned, such as no results found, I get an unexpected token exception when trying to parse the error. "Unexpected JSON token when reading DataTable. Expected StartArray, got StartObject"

The exact JSON returned is below:

```
{
  "error": {
     "message": "No Record found"
     "detail": "Records matching query not found. Check query parameter or offset parameter"
   }
   "status": "failure"
}
```

I've read a few similar issues and tried to make my own class but I'm not quite sure how exactly I should implement it.

Comment: Do you get HTTP status codes returned differently when you get an error message? If so, you could check the status code of the response and deserialize your response differently depending on the status code. You could create a simple class to match the error object - just match the properties of the json returned.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that it would return 404 or something, but it's just 200 OK with there text above.

Comment: I'm not 100% comfortable with this approach, but if they always return 200 you could always try and deserialize to your own "error" object in your catch block. Specifically catch the `UnexpectedTokenException` and try to deserialize to an error object instead. Keep the generic `catch (Exception e)` there as well.

Comment: Actually, I was not correct. I just checked again, it does return 404. So yes, I could work around this issue by examining the HTTP status.

Comment: Cool, do you know how to deserialize to an `Error` class or do you need some help?

Comment: Yep, should be good to go. Just never thought about working off of the status instead of the message. Thanks.

Comment: I assume that's not *The exact JSON* -- there should be commas between the properties, e.g. `"message": "No Record found", ...`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the web service isn't properly returning an error status, you could parse to an intermediate [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParsingLINQtoJSON.htm) then check to see if the response looks like an error or not:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(response.Content);
if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && ((JToken)"failure").Equals(token["status"]))
{
    // Handle error explicitly
    return null;
}

var dataset = token.ToObject<DataSet>();
var results = dataset.Tables["result"];
return results;
```

Alternatively you could catch the [`JsonException`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonException.htm) and check for an explicit error.  I don't really recommend this approach since it depends on the fact that the JSON for an error cannot be coincidentally deserialized as the JSON for a `DataSet`:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        var dataset = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(response.Content);
        var results = dataset.Tables["result"];

        return results;
    }
    catch (JsonException)
    {
        var token = JToken.Parse(response.Content);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object && ((JToken)"failure").Equals(token["status"]))
        {
            // Handle error explicitly
            return null;
        }
        // OK, it's not an explicit error. rethrow
        throw;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Generic error in the code somewhere.
    Debug.WriteLine(ex);
    // ... Other error handling as required
}
```

Comment: @Noobixide - I just finished this answer and read your comment that you are getting a proper 404 return after all.  Do you still need the answer?